# Android emulator with API R not working with latest android studio update

Tags: android-studio

Below is the error log from Android Studio.

```
3:10 PM Emulator: HVF error: HV_ERROR

3:10 PM Emulator: crashhandler_die: fatal: HVF fatal error

3:10 PM Emulator: 

3:10 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when testing API R in an emulator.
At the time I was using Android Studio 4.0. Updating Android Studio to version 4.1 (currently available only in canary channel) solved the issue.